# disable redirect after get_delete_post_link

Tags: wordpress, delete-file

When you click on a link that has the href value of:

```
get_delete_post_link( $id, $deprecated, $force_delete=false );
```

it deletes the attachment and automatically redirects you to the library. I would like to redirect to the current url instead.

I can use the the following function to achieve this:

```
add_action( 'trashed_post', 'redirect_after_trashing', 10 );
function redirect_after_trashing() {
    $absolute = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
    wp_redirect($absolute);
    exit;
}
```

but, when I use:

```
get_delete_post_link( $id, $deprecated, $force_delete=true );
```

it doesn't work. Does anyone know of another solution?

Answer (score 0):

$force_delete == false will trash the post

$force_delete == true will delete the post

For hook into deleting a post look for this hook:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/delete_post

Comment: This redirects the page... but it doesn't delete the post before redirection.